# Javascript chat using socket.io : my code doesn't work while teacher's does (seem a lot the same)

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm following a JS course and I can't understand why my code doesn't work but the teacher's code does work. It seems like it's an "order of lines" thing but I'm not sure and can't figure this out.

More specifically, the functionality that doesn't work is the chat (the socket part).

Here's the teacher's code that works :

```
const express = require('express')
const session = require('express-session')
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)
const flash = require('connect-flash')
const markdown = require('marked')
const app = express()
const sanitizeHTML = require('sanitize-html')

let sessionOptions = session({
  secret: "JavaScript is sooooooooo coool",
  store: new MongoStore({client: require('./db')}),
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, httpOnly: true}
})

app.use(sessionOptions)
app.use(flash())

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // make our markdown function available from within ejs templates
  res.locals.filterUserHTML = function(content) {
    return sanitizeHTML(markdown(content), {allowedTags: ['p', 'br', 'ul', 'ol', 'li', 'strong', 'bold', 'i', 'em', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6'], allowedAttributes: {}})
  }
  
  // make all error and success flash messages available from all templates
  res.locals.errors = req.flash("errors")
  res.locals.success = req.flash("success")

  // make current user id available on the req object
  if (req.session.user) {req.visitorId = req.session.user._id} else {req.visitorId = 0}
  
  // make user session data available from within view templates
  res.locals.user = req.session.user
  next()
})

const router = require('./router')

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(express.json())

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.set('views', 'views')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use('/', router)

const server = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)

io.use(function(socket, next) {
  sessionOptions(socket.request, socket.request.res, next)
})

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  if (socket.request.session.user) {
    let user = socket.request.session.user

    socket.emit('welcome', {username: user.username, avatar: user.avatar})

    socket.on('chatMessageFromBrowser', function(data) {
      socket.broadcast.emit('chatMessageFromServer', {message: sanitizeHTML(data.message, {allowedTags: [], allowedAttributes: {}}), username: user.username, avatar: user.avatar})
    })
  }
})

module.exports = server
```

And here's my code, that seems a lot the same but doesn't work :

```
const express = require('express')
const session = require('express-session')
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)
const flash = require('connect-flash')
const markdown = require('marked')
const sanitizeHTML = require('sanitize-html')
const app = express()

let sessionOptions = session({
    secret: "Javacsript is soooooooo coooooool",
    store: new MongoStore({client: require('./db')}),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
        httpOnly: true
    }
})

const router = require('./router')

app.use(sessionOptions)
app.use(flash())
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // Make our markdown function available from within ejs templates
    res.locals.filterUserHTML = function(content) {
        return sanitizeHTML(markdown(content), {allowedTags: ['p', 'br', 'ul', 'ol', 'li', 'bold', 'i', 'em', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6'], allowedAttributes: {}})
    }
    // Make all error and success flash messages available from all templates
    res.locals.errors = req.flash("errors")
    res.locals.success = req.flash("success")
    // Make user session data available from within view template
    res.locals.user = req.session.user
    // Make current user id available on the req object
    if (req.session.user) {req.visitorId = req.session.user._id} else {req.visitorId = 0}
    next()
})
// Add user submitted data to route
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(express.json())

app.use('/', router)
app.use(express.static('public'))
// For views (1st arg), look into the folder 'views' (2nd arg)
app.set('views', 'views')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

const server = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)

io.use(function(socket, next) {
    sessionOptions(socket.request, socket.request.res, next)
})

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    if (socket.request.session.user) {
        let user = socket.request.session.user

        socket.emit('welcome', {username: user.username, avatar: user.avatar})

        socket.on('chatMessageFromServer', function(data) {
            // Emit the event to all connected users except the one who sent it
            socket.broadcast.emit('chatMessageFromServer', {
                message: sanitizeHTML(data.message, {allowedTags: [], allowedAttributes: {}}), 
                username: user.username, 
                avatar: user.avatar})
        })
    }
})

module.exports = server
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It helps if you specify where they differ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you misnamed your listener. (`socket.on` function)

`chatMessageFromServer` should be `chatMessageFromBrowser`.

Comment: Good catch, dude.  I've been scanning the diffs and totally missed that.

Comment: Well done Daniel, thanks a lot for your hawk eye :)